# Language fallback to site default in internationalization

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

This should be simple enough; but, I'm trying it since a day now with no success.

My site contains listing pages or different content types. By default all the content is of language "English".
When a user (author) translates a content in the listing to other language (say Spanish), and switches to that language using "language switcher"; only nodes of that language are being listed.
This is because I've added `Content: Language (= Current user's language)` filter to the view.

What I require is when a node does not have a Spanish translation, it should show that node in English. In short I want "English" as a fallback language to all the views (and site). I've tried ORing the filters so that I could list "current language" OR "English", but it shows the both the translated nodes and their corresponding nodes in "English", which is obvious.

**Note** I've made it compulsory for a user to select content for every content type.

I've tried [Language Fallback](https://drupal.org/project/language_fallback) module, but it did not work.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was useless (with its own language switcher, entity translation fallback language option work fine but for nodes, not views). Now just in case :  at the moment the "official" Language Fallback project doesn't provide a view feature, but there is a full rewrited project available from https://github.com/globalbility/custom-modules-theme that provides a language filter option in views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is this module: [Select translation](https://drupal.org/project/select_translation)

> The options are : Use current language ; if not available use original language

I've used it before and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to have a View with a default language fallback: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/229445/55122